# Is there an official twitter account for the Graphic Design Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, site-promotion

Some of the other Stack Exchange sites have their own twitter accounts either run by SE inc. or by prominent users on the sites. does anything like this exist for the graphic design site, or will we have to wait until the site graduates from beta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is. The account is @StackDesign. One can see most of the stack exchange sites by seeing [who the main Stack Exchange Account follows](https://twitter.com/#!/StackExchange/following).